# Как вписать href в код JS?

Tags: javascript, java, html, button, href

Я не программист, и вообще первый раз в жизни ковыряюсь с кодом. Просто нужно сделать расширение на JS, которое добавило бы кнопку в плеер модифицированного клиента Спотифая, при нажатии которой открывалась бы вкладка другого расширения. Кое как, методом тыка, по примеру других расширений и коду HTML мне удалось сделать кнопку. Но так как я абсолютно не знаю ни одни язык программирования - я никак не могу привязать к ней действие.

Код моего расширения:

```
(function spotifyLyrics() {
if (!Spicetify.LocalStorage) {
    setTimeout(spotifyLyrics, 1000);
    return;
}


function createLyricsButton() {
    const b = document.createElement("button");
    b.classList.add("button", "button", "button-lyrics", "spoticon-lyrics-16");
    b.id = "lyricsButton"
    b.onclick = () => {
        if (href="spotify:app:genius") {
            closeNav();
        } else {
            openNav();
        }
    };
    return b;
}

const extraControlsContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("extra-controls-container");
extraControlsContainer[0].prepend(createLyricsButton()); // prepend = append before all
```

})();

Клиент Спотифая работает на Хроме, так что там так же, как и в браузере можно смотреть, и редактировать HTML код. И если в нём, к строчке

```
<button class="button button-lyrics spoticon-lyrics-16" id="lyricsButton"></button>
```

Добавить

```
href="spotify:app:genius"
```

Что бы вышло

```
<button class="button button-lyrics spoticon-lyrics-16" href="spotify:app:genius" id="lyricsButton"></button>
```

То всё работает как надо, просто идеально. Вопрос лишь в том, как вписать этот href в код расширения. Полагаю, что в ту часть, где b.onclick, но я уже десятки разных вариантов перепробовал, гуглил примеры, и ничего не выходит. Помогите пожалуйста :c

Comment: В данном случае это атрибут `b.setAttribute('href','spotify:app:genius')`. Только вот я не пойму, что это за логика - вот здесь `if (href="spotify:app:genius")`?

Comment: @Alexander Lonberg, Спасибо огромное. Заработало. 'if (href="spotify:app:genius")' - безпоняятия что это. Кусок кода, оставшийся от какого то другого расширения, по примеру которого я пытался что то сделать. '(href="spotify:app:genius")' точно я вписывал, а без 'if' кнопка вообще пропадает.

Comment: Или можно было просто button заменить на a))) если класс button все равно должна выглядеть как кнопка